# is there a better way to write this jquery so it's only 3 functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-cleanup

So I'm not that great at jquery, but is there a way to merge the code for all the same clicks so I only have 3 functions? A more function, a next function,  and a close function. I've tried and when I do they end up not working and break.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.more').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });

    $('a.more').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().addClass('hide');
    });

    $('a.more').click(function(){
        var load = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+load+'1').load(''+load+'.html');
    });

    $('a.close').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('.card').removeClass('active');
    });

    $("a.close").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('hide');
    });
    $('a.close').click(function(){
        var load = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+load+'1').empty();
    });

    $('a.next').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('.card').removeClass('active');
    });

    $('a.next').click(function(){
        var load = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+load+'1').empty();
    });

    $('a.next').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('.card').addClass('hide');
    });

    $('a.next').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next('.card').removeClass('hide');
    });

    $('a.next').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next('.card').addClass('active');
    });

    $('a.next').click(function(){
        var load = $(this).parent().next('.card').attr('id');
        $('#'+load+'1').load(''+load+'.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: Consider posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why are you not combining them?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: no reason they should break  unless you had invalid syntax when done

Comment: I've never heard of that site actually, sorry. I'll bookmark it. And I don't know why,I tried multiple times to try and combine like the answers and it ended up breaking. But Alex's copy-pasta works perfect; sometimes I hate technology :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just combine the contents of the event handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.more').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().addClass('hide');
        var load = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+load+'1').load(''+load+'.html');
    });

    $('a.close').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('.card').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('hide');
        var load = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+load+'1').empty();
    });

    $('a.next').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('.card').removeClass('active');
        var load = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+load+'1').empty();
        $(this).parent('.card').addClass('hide');
        $(this).parent().next('.card').removeClass('hide');
        $(this).parent().next('.card').addClass('active');
        var load = $(this).parent().next('.card').attr('id');
        $('#'+load+'1').load(''+load+'.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I was not aware of the other site.

Answer (score 0):

This should work ...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $('a.more').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().siblings().addClass('hide');
            var load = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            $('#'+load+'1').load(''+load+'.html');
   });
.. etc same for other functions
```

Just merge the parts that are for the same event into one function.

Or to be more efficient as le commenteur pointed out ..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $('a.more').click(function(){
            var elParent=$(this).parent;
            elParent.addClass('active');
            elParent.siblings().addClass('hide');
            var load = elParent.attr('id');
            $('#'+load+'1').load(''+load+'.html');
   });
.. etc same for other functions
```

Comment: DRY alert :) $(this).parent() you are doing this 3 times

Comment: "DRY"? not familiar with that ...

Comment: Don't Repeat Yourself

Comment: $(this).parent().addClass('active'); $(this).parent().siblings().addClass('hide') , this could be var _parent $(this).parent

Comment: The variable one actually didn't work when I copy-pasta(ed) it.

Comment: @Alexandros Spyropoulous Ah - well that wasn't really part of the question, so I don't feel too guilty about that.

Answer (score 0):

there are pretty much many things that could be optimised. in general you need to use more the dot syntax and avoid remaking jquery objects and use more than one listener for the same selector, because they cost in performance. I will not rewrite your code but I will give a few tips

starting with user2808054 answer for example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('a.more').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().addClass('hide');
        var load = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+load+'1').load(''+load+'.html');
});
```

could be written

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#whatever').click(function () {
       var _parent = $(this).parent(),
       _id = _parent.attr('id');

       _parent.addClass('active').siblings().addClass('hide');
       $('#' + _id + '1').load('' + _id + '.html');
    });
 })
```

and if you want to stay tight in variables

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#whatever').click(function () {
       var _parent = $(this).parent();
       _parent.addClass('active').siblings().addClass('hide');
       $('#' + _parent.attr('id') + '1').load('' + _parent.attr('id') + '.html');
    });
 })
```

also there is no reason in spliting the same listener in many, that costs resourses, instead do one listener, if now you want to split the logic do the logic in separate functions and call them from your listener instead.

I would prefer this format though because it's cleaner and you write for people, not for machines.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#whatever').click(function () {
       var _parent = $(this).parent(),
       _id = _parent.attr('id');

       _parent
         .addClass('active')
         .siblings()
           .addClass('hide');

       $('#' + _id + '1')
         .load('' + _id + '.html');
    });
  });
```